# How to get the parameter count, and the parameter string in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I used unix bash before, and I can't find any commands in powershell similar to $* or $#

I've found out that $* is $args
But what is $#
This doesn't work:

```
$args.toString().split(" ").length;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haven't done this for a while, but it should work like this.

```
$* : $args
$# : $args.count
$1 : $args[0]
```

Code untested.

Answer (score 1):

$args is an array, so $args.Length should do the trick...

Answer (score 1):

Better option is to declare named parameters using param()

Comment: Perhaps make this a comment instead of an answer?